# How to use NLTK stem

Tags: python, nltk

Silly, but I am somehow not able to access the stem functions in NLTK.

I call

```
import nltk
nltk.stem.porter.step1ab()
```

but I get told that object has no step1ab attribute. I guess I am somehow not calling it correctly, but I'm unsure how to actually get to it.

Comment: oh and 
`from nltk.stem import porter
porter.steb1ab()`
produces the same results

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`step1ab()` is a method of the class `PorterStemmer` within the *nltk.stem.porter* module. So you can call it like this:

```
myPorterStemmer = nltk.stem.porter.PorterStemmer()
...
myPorterStemmer.step1ab()
```

However, it's not really designed to be called directly. One would usually call `myPorterStemmer.stem(word)`, which would then delegate to `step1ab()` to do part of the work.

If you really want to use `step1ab` in isolation though, you would have to set a bunch of variables and you'd get something like this:

```
>>> word = "countries"
>>> myStemmer = nltk.stem.porter.PorterStemmer()
>>> myStemmer.b = word
>>> myStemmer.k = len(word) - 1
>>> myStemmer.k0 = 0
>>> myStemmer.step1ab()
>>> myStemmer.b[myStemmer.k0:myStemmer.k+1]
'countri'
```

Comment: Thanks- worked a treat! One more thing if you happen to know the answer- when I then try to call `myPorterStemmer.step1ab()` I get a TypeError: `TypeError: step1ab() takes exactly 1 argument (2 given)`. So it's similar to [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4909585/interesting-takes-exactly-1-argument-2-given-python-error) but I can't actually figure how to make it work. Sorry- still a python n00b!

Comment: @penguin: I updated the answer to show how you can call `step1ab`. However, I think you might actually just want to call `myStemmer.stem(word)` instead, as that is much easier and does all the steps in one go.