# Inheriting a base class for nose tests

Tags: python, python-2.7, nose

I'm trying to implement an integration test framework using nose. At the core, I'd like a base class that all test classes inherit. I'd like to have a class setup function that is called as well as the per test setup function. When I use `nosetests a_file.py -vs` where *a_file.py* looks like this:

```
    from nose import tools

    class BaseClass(object):
        def __init__(self):
            print 'Initialize Base Class'

        def setup(self):
            print "\nBase Setup"

        def teardown(self):
            print "Base Teardown"

        @tools.nottest
        def a_test(self):
            return 'This is a test.'

        @tools.nottest
        def another_test(self):
            return 'This is another test'

    class TestSomeStuff(BaseClass):
        def __init__(self):
            BaseClass.__init__(self)
            print 'Initialize Inherited Class'

        def setup(self):
            BaseClass.setup(self)
            print "Inherited Setup"

        def teardown(self):
            BaseClass.teardown(self)
            print 'Inherited Teardown'

        def test1(self):
            print self.a_test()

        def test2(self):
            print self.another_test()
```

Outputs this:

```
Initialize Base Class
Initialize Inherited Class
Initialize Base Class
Initialize Inherited Class
cases.nose.class_super.TestSomeStuff.test1 ... 
Base Setup
Inherited Setup
This is a test.
Base Teardown
Inherited Teardown
ok
cases.nose.class_super.TestSomeStuff.test2 ... 
Base Setup
Inherited Setup
This is another test
Base Teardown
Inherited Teardown
ok

----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 2 tests in 0.001s

OK
```

How do I make the `__init__`, `setup`, and `teardown` functions class methods? When I attempt this:

```
from nose import tools

class BaseClass(object):
    def __init__(self):
        print 'Initialize Base Class'

    @classmethod
    def setup_class(self):
        print "\nBase Setup"

    @classmethod
    def teardown_class(self):
        print "Base Teardown"

    @tools.nottest
    def a_test(self):
        return 'This is a test.'

    @tools.nottest
    def another_test(self):
        return 'This is another test'

class TestSomeStuff(BaseClass):
    def __init__(self):
        BaseClass.__init__(self)
        print 'Initialize Inherited Class'

    @classmethod
    def setup_class(self):
        BaseClass.setup_class(self)
        print "Inherited Setup"

    @classmethod
    def teardown_class(self):
        BaseClass.teardown_class(self)
        print 'Inherited Teardown'

    def test1(self):
        print self.a_test()

    def test2(self):
        print self.another_test()
```

I get this:

```
Initialize Base Class
Initialize Inherited Class
Initialize Base Class
Initialize Inherited Class
ERROR

======================================================================
ERROR: test suite for <class 'cases.nose.class_super.TestSomeStuff'>
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/nose/suite.py", line 208, in run
    self.setUp()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/nose/suite.py", line 291, in setUp
    self.setupContext(ancestor)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/nose/suite.py", line 314, in setupContext
    try_run(context, names)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/nose/util.py", line 478, in try_run
    return func()
  File "/home/ryan/project/python_testbed/cases/nose/class_super.py", line 30, in setup_class
    BaseClass.setup_class(self)
TypeError: setup_class() takes exactly 1 argument (2 given)

----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 0 tests in 0.001s

FAILED (errors=1)
```

Removing the `self` from the super class calls (`BaseClass.setup_class(self)` -> `BaseClass.setup_class()`) seems to fix it...which I don't understand:

```
Initialize Base Class
Initialize Inherited Class
Initialize Base Class
Initialize Inherited Class

Base Setup
Inherited Setup
cases.nose.class_super.TestSomeStuff.test1 ... This is a test.
ok
cases.nose.class_super.TestSomeStuff.test2 ... This is another test
ok
Base Teardown
Inherited Teardown

----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 2 tests in 0.001s

OK
```

However, this doesn't help with the `__init__` function. How can I make this a class method? Why does passing in `self` to the super class fail?

Does anyone have some info on this?

Answer (score 2):

Class methods take a single implicit argument, (called `cls` by convention, although you have called it `self` too), like instance methods take `self`.

When you call

```
BaseClass.setup_class(self)
```

It's really more like

```
BaseClass.setup_class(BaseClass, self)
```

hence the warning over two arguments. Therefore it's fixed when you ditch `self`; as a reminder, change the definitions:

```
@classmethod
def setup_class(cls):
```

Oh, and `__init__` makes no sense as a `@classmethod`; it's for setting up instances.

Comment: You might find this question useful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1269217/calling-a-base-classs-classmethod-in-python

Comment: I understand that __init__ makes no sense as a class method, but it is the __init__ function for the object...the fact that it is ran 2 times tells me that nose is creating a new object for each test...is this true?

Comment: Yes, it appears to be creating two instances of the `TestSomeStuff` class

Comment: I guess I'll go with it...I don't really understand why it creates an object for each test, or why it doesn't just pass `self` instead of this `cls` argument. Is there any documentation on this I can read up on? Am I missing something in the nose docs?

Comment: For information on classes, instances, class methods, see [here](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#types). There is more information on what happens internally to `nosetest` [here](https://nose.readthedocs.org/en/latest/api.html).

Answer (score 1):

Looks like @Jonrsharpe already beat me, but yeah.  I'll post it anyway.

[This one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4909585/interesting-takes-exactly-1-argument-2-given-python-error) might explain the setup_class() error.  It is passing in an instance of BaseClass as well as 'self' (or TestSomeStuff) when you include the self.  Nose must be hard coded to not allow more then 1 parameter in that function (or Unittest, not sure which one has that requirement).

As for the **init** part, after reading through the Unittest documentation, it appears that the code would be better printed as:

```
def __init__(self):
        print 'Initialize Base Class Object'
```

And:

```
def __init__(self):
    BaseClass.__init__(self)
    print 'Initialize Inherited Class Object'
```

Since it's basically creating an object for every test case and running that **init** function to make sure the test case is ready.